# Term reference translation

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

I am using term reference in "select list" configuration. I do not know how to translate them, I have Taxonomy translation and Entity translation activated, but none of them worked.

Even I have already done the Field display translation settings and also the taxonomy translation settings!

Can you please give a guide? thank you

Answer (score 1):

While adding vocabulary, you need to select third option for translate your     vocabulary and its terms. Ref. attached image.

[image]

After adding the terms and its translation, and configured term reference as a "select list", you can see there are both translated terms shows into select list while adding a content.

Hope it will be helpful.